# Can't use Lambda expressions in Windows services?

Tags: c#, windows-services, lambda

I've developed a server software for .net 3.5 which I tried to convert to a windows service application. So I created a new Windows service project and added all my classes. But I can't compile it because it doesn't understand the lambda expressions i've used. I've checked so that all references are imported. But it seems like it isn't possible to change the target framework in a windows service project and I suspect that it's the problem.

Comment: Next time, please do basic spell checking before posting a question.

Comment: In this case, I meant the "sindows" in the title. I don't really care about minor mistakes, but spelling a product name wrong in the question title makes searching harder :)

Comment: I have windows services written in .NET 3.5 running with lambda, so it's not a framework problem. Please post the compile error. And be sure you selected .NET Framework 3.5 as your destination framework (Project properties).

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use the LINQ extension methods but you don't import System.Linq it won't compile. Try:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your references.  Sounds like you are missing a required type.  If you post the entire compiler error and maybe some sample code we could probably provide more insight.